# Reading Big Dump file

Tags: mysql, xml, file

I have exported a **sample.xml** file from MySQL DB. The size of the file is approximately 9.5 GB. **Can anyone please suggest me an external tool, so I can customised which specific columns I want in my exported XMl file.** As I saw in XAMPP, there is no advanced option for choosing the specific columns while exporting to XML file. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few options:

- You could [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html) for a subset of columns, and then export the view to XML.
- You could design an XSL script and filter the XML output with [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).
- You could export all columns, but then choose which columns to import with [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html).

Comment: #2 and #3 wouldn't decrease the initial file size, which I understand is the main problem. #1 is the solution I would prefer as it has some more advantages like disjoin the export from physical data structure etc.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin, I tried with first option and it works. Thanks again for sharing the information :)